# Bootstrap en jsPDF Angular

Tags: bootstrap, angular, jspdf

Tengo una plantilla HTML donde le aplico estilos de Bootstrap, pero cuando lo convierto a PDF no toma los estilos de Bootstrap.

Quería saber si hay una solución para eso en Angular, actualmente uso la libreria jsPDF.

Mi código:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="text-center">
    CONSTANCIA
  </h1>
</div>


<button (click)="descargarPDF()">
     Exportar PDF
    </button>
```

-TS:

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("content") content: ElementRef;
  hola = "hola";
  descargarPDF() {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let specialElement = {
      '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    let contens = this.content.nativeElement;

    doc.fromHTML(contens.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 190,
      'elementHandlers': specialElement
    })
    doc.save('test.pdf');

  }

}
```

Comment: Pues mira para lo que estás haciendo dentro de lo que investigué y ya logré hacer, usé html2canvas, te permite realizar algo así como una captura de lo que hay dentro de una sección de html. te dejo el link con su documentación:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas